# javascript switch (option) with multiple variables

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have made this function here to calculate prices from choices in the select menu. I have made a switch but I dont understand where to input my function to trigger it (on html). The 2 other functions changeit() and changerepas() are onchange functions that will give you the basic price. (they are not linked to the question) (Note: This is my first switch ever, so it might look noobish to most of you. )

```js
function taxesrepas(option){
    var soustot;
    var taxes;
    var taxer;
    var taxetotal = taxes + taxer;
    var total = taxetotal + soustot;
    var pricee;
    var pricer;
    var soustot = pricee + pricer;



    switch (option){
        case "spaghetti":
        taxer = 0.69;
        pricer = 8.95
        break;    
        case "lasagne":
        taxer = 0.75;
        pricer = 9.95;
        break;
        case "salade":
        taxes = 0.45;
        pricee = 5.95;
        break;
        case "escargot":
        taxes = 0.38;
        pricee = 4.95;
        break;
   }
        document.getElementById("taxes").innerHTML = taxetotal;
        document.getElementbyid("total").innerHTML = total;
        document.getElementbyid("soustot").innerHTML = soustot;

    }
```

```html
<select name="entree" id="entree" onChange="changeit(this.value)">
    <option value="hidden" selected>Choisir...</option>
    <option value="salade">Salade</option>
    <option value="escargot">Escargot</option>
  </select>
<img display="inline" id="imgselect" src="" alt="0.00$"/>
<h3 id= "choix1"></h3>
<p>Repas</p>   
<select name="repas" id="repas" onChange="changerepas(this.value)">
    <option value="hidden1" selected>Choisir...</option>
    <option value="spaghetti">Spaghetti</option>
    <option value="lasagne">Lasagne</option>
  </select>
<h3 id="choix"></h3>
<h3 id="taxes"></h3>
<h3 id="soustotal"></h3>
<h3 id="total"></h3>
```

Comment: Just add on-click event to any element (`button` for example), and fire your `taxesrepas` function when triggered. Docs: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: you can internally call switch method inside changeit or changerepas function, where according to the menu changes taxes and total will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change the onChange to

```
function(){
  taxesrepas(this.value);
  changeit(this.value); 
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by fire taxesrepas function ?

Comment: I just dont understand where to put my function in the HTML to start it right.

Comment: Ok, let me know

Comment: Ive created some <h3> to give me my results, how can i make these h3 start my function ?

Comment: Why h3 tags shall start the function?

Comment: Because i want to return them in a certain style that i have designed with css. I want the function to give me the results inside these h3 tags

Comment: You can use innerHTML like you done in your code to change the text inside the h3 tags

Comment: but my function is not returning anything for some reason... I cant find why